# Shared directory in linux server

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-permissions

We have a vps server. We want to share some files across all user accounts. Now users cannot access the file unless he is the owner of that file. How can we create a shared directory such that every users can access the files inside it, even though they are not owners of that files.

eg:- of user's directories

```
/home/user1/public_html
/home/user2/public_html
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit about the Linux permissions:

```
ls -lah
drwx------  2 username groupname 4.0K Feb 17 21:34 filename
```

drwx----- gives you information about the permissions on a file/folder

d meaning it is a folder then its 3 characters for user,group and others

d{rwx} meaning that the user 'username' in this case has read write and execute permissions
d{rwx}{rw} for example would mean that the group 'groupname' would have read/write permissions.

Knowing this you can make a folder and assign permissions:

```
mkdir public_folder
chmod g+rw public_folder
```

This will changemod group and give it read/write permissions, you can also use o+rw to give others (everyone) read/write permissions. But from a security perspective you might want to put the users in a group and give that group permission

```
chgrp yourgroupname public_folder
```

Will change the group to 'yourgroupname'

Answer (score 0):

Create a new group for users who are supposed to be able to access the shared directory.  Then set the directory's group membership to that group with chown.  Now whatever the group permissions are set to will apply to members of that group.  Add the desired users to the group, and you'll have a shared directory managed by the directory owner.

If you need the repository to be read-write for everyone, then chmod g+s the folder to make it setgid.  This will force all files and subdirectories created under it to be owned by the same group as the shared folder.  Now users can add files to the directory, and other members of the group will be able access them based on their group permissions, while the person who added them will be able to access them based on their user permissions.

See man chown and man chmod for details of how to set user/group ownership and user/group permissions on files.